# Материал действует только на часть объекта Unity3D

Tags: unity3d

У меня есть машинка, которую я скачал из Asset Store [вот ссылка на ассет](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/3d/vehicles/land/low-poly-cars-101798).

Я хочу наложить на нее материал с эффектом обводки, используя [этот скрипт и материал](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/particles-effects/quick-outline-115488). Скрипт добавляет в конец списка материалов материал обводки.

Но когда я добавляю компонент `Outline` На свою машинку, то он работает некорректно (или вообще не работает, я этого понять не могу). Для сравнения, этот скрипт и материал работают правильно для других объектов:

[image: Дерево и светофор обводятся, машинка нет]

Еще я заметил(и подозреваю, что в этом главная проблема), что если я добавляю материалы в список материалов то они применяются к фарам почему-то:

[image: С новым материалом]

[image: Без нового материала]

Как мне сделать, чтобы обводка сработала, причем на всю машинку?

Comment: объект разделен на разные и список этих материалов соответствует своему объекту, тебе не нужно добавлять в конец списка материал, тебе нужно  заменить существующие 3 на новые

Comment: Как мне переписать шейдер материала поверхности машины так, чтобы получилась обводка? Я в шейдерах профан

Comment: зависит от технологий, если у вас проект на URP, то практичней использовать ShaderGraph, а вообще шейдеры это очень большая тема и не мало работы, возможно найдется человек, который перепишет вам его, но я бы особо не надеялся

Comment: Тогда плохи мои дела. Мне нужно сделать за 2 недели, делаю я сам, а все мои попытки ознакомиться с GLSL и ShaderGraph закончились крахом...

Comment: попробуй поискать другой шейдер сразу с задаваемым цветом и оутлайном и без скриптов.

Comment: @Some_Person попробуй этот [asset](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/particles-effects/quick-outline-115488). Раньше его использовал и радовался

Comment: @Methorn, это и есть тот ассет, который я использую)

Comment: @Some_Person тогда извиняюсь